What is the difference between data type with eight implied decimal places and four implied decimal places?
I am changing the data type in some of my code, and I have two definitions, but do not quite understand the distinction.
Price: 'Signed Little-Endian encoded eight byte integer field with eight
implied decimal places.'
Price i4: 'Signed Little-Endian encoded eight byte integer field with four
implied decimal places.'
In my current code/fields, they have the Price datatype, but I want to change it to Price i4.
Any ideas firstly what the difference between the two are?
Nothing to experiment with.
